# Turn off SSL Verification on WSO2 Integration Studio / Micro Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I created a project in WSO2 Integration Studio and when making the call to an external API, which has an invalid SSL (development server), the error below is presented, which I ask: Is it possible to turn off SSL verification, at least for the development server? How to do it?

[image: Call created on WSO2 Integration Studio]

```
[2020-12-02 10:10:11,254]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:MyAPI} To: /myAPI/get-token, MessageID: urn:uuid:6e2733f6-9bad-4674-bfbf-122909ddf437, Direction: request, welcomeGetToken = MyAPI: GetToken Entry
[2020-12-02 10:10:11,256]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:MyAPI} To: /myAPI/get-token,MessageID: urn:uuid:6e2733f6-9bad-4674-bfbf-122909ddf437,Direction: request,Username = ,Password = 
[2020-12-02 10:10:11,362]  WARN {TargetHandler} - ERROR_CODE = 101500, STATE_DESCRIPTION = Exception occurred when Server establishing a connection to the backend, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_READY, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = I/O exception : General SSLEngine problem, TARGET_HOST = 222.22.222.22, TARGET_PORT = 443, TARGET_CONTEXT = https://dev.myserver.pt/get-token, HTTP_METHOD = POST, TRIGGER_TYPE = api, TRIGGER_NAME = MyAPI, REMOTE_ADDRESS = dev.myserver.pt/222.22.222.22:443, CONNECTION = http-outgoing-2
[2020-12-02 10:10:11,364] ERROR {TargetHandler} - I/O error: General SSLEngine problem javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1566)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:545)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1217)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1185)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:471)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:198)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1729)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:333)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:325)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1688)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:226)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1082)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:1015)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:1012)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1504)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:293)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:450)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:317)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:289)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1675)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:445)
    ... 23 more

[2020-12-02 10:10:11,367]  WARN {EndpointContext} - Endpoint : EvidenceGetToken with address https://dev.myserver.pt/token will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2020-12-02 10:10:11,369]  WARN {EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : EvidenceGetToken with address https://dev.myserver.pt/token - last suspend duration was : 30000ms and current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Wed Dec 02 10:10:41 WET 2020
```

Comment: You have to import the public certificate of the server where the endpoint is hosted into client-truststore.jks file

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan, but isn't possible deactive ssl verification?

Comment: I don't think so. HTTPS always need SSL verification from WSO2 integration perspective